# How to catch errors in Bash from /dev/tcp?

Tags: bash, tcp, error-handling

I have a moderate understanding of how to use trap but cannot for the life of me figure out how to catch an error returned from /dev/tcp.

When running "cat < /dev/tcp/$URL/$PORT" where the URL is a server that results in "connect: Connection refused" I can't figure out how to catch that error.

If anyone has any insight on how to use trap in this case, that would be extremely helpful. The current way that I handle it is this:

```
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    echo "error"
fi
```

and that allows me to be able to commit an action if an error occurs, but this is the only way I know how to handle this specific issue. Not the right way to do it, I know, but it is the only thing I could get to work.

If anyone has any insight how to solve this problem in Bash that would be great. And no, I cannot use netcat instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trap allows you to catch signals, but it is not a general exception management facility I'm afraid.

One thing you *could* try would be to catch the output of the "cat" command and check if it contained information on the error (especially if the return value of cat is not zero). Otherwise, not much is really possible here inside of the shell.

Answer (score 5):

The error comes directly from Bash and not from cat. Thus the redirection operators are useless.

I'm still searching for a means to wipe out the connect error message.

Still the error condition can be evaluated :

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/${2}/${3} || {
    echo "PROBLEM"
    exit 1
}
```

An modified version of the above test could be :

```
#!/bin/bash

# args: #1: host, #2: port

(exec 3<>/dev/tcp/${1}/${2}) &>/dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
    echo "PROBLEM"
    exit 1
fi
```

Obviously this version does not open fd 3 for the caller but is intended to discard the error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch the entire error, the best way is to redirect entire error to a file. File descriptor 2 which is steer is used for displaying errors and these will be displayed on console.
Use
echo >/dev/tcp/ Host/port  2> filename
Now your file name has error. 
You can read the file in bash script using $( cat filename )

If you don't want to display error redirect to /dev/null instead of a file.